# typed nested json decoding in go

Tags: json, data-structures, go

I try to Unmarshal some nested JSON in go, the structs go something along this

```
type GameState struct {
  missiles []*Missile
  others   []*Player
  you      *Player
}
type Message struct {
  gamestate   *GameState
  messagetype string
}
// json like {"gamestate":{...},"messagetype":"stateupdate"}
```

I've also put a [running example](https://play.golang.org/p/M234bEOEwc) online.

Now when I use ***map[string]interface{}*** to Unmarshal everything gets deserialized. But the moment I use the structs to Unmarshal I get nil back, both as result and error.

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All struct fields you want to marshal should start with uppercase letter (be public). This works https://play.golang.org/p/ReCp3BAfTb